# Are there any studies on the success of day traders?

Tags: stocks, stock-markets, broker, risk-management, research

If you know about any published research paper on trade accuracy or from broker perspective that what percentage of clients are profitable in day trading.

Comment: https://mathinvestor.org/2020/07/day-trading-in-the-age-of-coronavirus/

Comment: Also worth noting if you don't know the answer to this question already and why, you're definitely not one of the profitable ones.

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Day_trading#Profitability_and_risks) cites some studies on profitability, and they are not encouraging.

Comment: what does trade accuracy have to do with profitability?

Comment: @mhoran_psprep might I suggest, if there's an obviously badly / incorrectly written headline (perhaps by a non-English speaker) might as well just fix it rather than asking rhetorical questions etc .. ?

Comment: https://faculty.haas.berkeley.edu/odean/papers/Day%20Traders/Day%20Trading%20and%20Learning%20110217.pdf

Comment: @Flux That should be an answer. It cites exactly the studies the question is looking for.

Comment: The Wikipedia article makes some simplified generalizations that don't fit all traders. The mathinvestor article is dead on about  most day traders losing money. I'm going to take the other side of the argument since I'm among that minority that has made money from trading. I retired young and since then my objective has been to augment my income without large losses and to not spend down my nest egg. I've achieved that in most years except in 2008-09 when I was net short and improved my net worth significantly. Overall, I haven't beaten the market (that wasn't my objective). This can be done.

Comment: @BobBaerker "Overall, I *haven't* beaten the market (that wasn't my objective)" — Did you make a typo here?

Comment: No typo. During my first 20+ years of investing, I did very well during the 80's bull market and the 90's Internet craze. I got out of the way of the Internet Bubble so little harm done there.  Having accumulated enough to retire early, I began trading to augment my income.  My goals were to 1) not lose much if any of the nest egg and 2) avoid spending down the nest egg in retirement (both achieved since most years, I have grown my nest egg). With the exception of 2008-2009, over the past 15 years I have not outperformed the market. But given my goals, that does not bother me in the slightest.

Comment: relevant: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qhHOmZVAqBE&t=532s&ab_channel=BenFelix